# Calculate $P(|X-4| > 1.5)$

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

If $X \sim U(2, 8)$

Would it be $$P(X > 1.5 + 4) + P(X <-1.5 +4)$$

Comment: Yes, you are correct!

Answer (score 2):

You got it. Just follow through with that thought.

$$\begin{split}
P(\left| X-4 \right|) > 1.5) &= P(X > 5.5) + P(X < 2.5) \\
&= \frac{2.5}{6} + \frac{0.5}{6} \\
&= \frac12
\end{split}$$

Comment: Thanks. Got the same answer as well. much appreciated